# How to prove a specific sequence is Fibonacci's with no prior knowledge nor trial and error?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, alternative-proof

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $s_n$ be the number of increasing sequences of integers, alternatingly even and odd, starting with $0$ and ending with $n$. E.g. for $n=3$ we only have the two sequences $$ 0,1,2,3 \ \  \text{and} \ \ 0,3.$$ hence $s_3=2$. Prove that the $s_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers.

Here's the deal. We *already* know that the sequence is Fibonacci's, so it suffices to show that $s_n$ satisfies the recursive definition of $F_n$. And it is in fact straightforward to put the sequences for $n=k,k+1$ into one-to-one correspondence with those for $n=k+2$.
So what I'm looking for is an approach able to *find*  that $s_n=F_n$, without knowing it beforehand or guessing.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking: are you looking for an algorithm that will take the definition of the $s_n$ and the definition of the $F_n$ and decide whether the two sequences are equal?

Comment: @RobArthan Mark Bennet and "poor Jack" got what I meant.

Comment: So your question was "how do I prove $s_n = F_n$"? Forgive me for thinking that you had something else in mind when you said you wanted an approach that could "find" this fact.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, without already knowing it. That is, I wouldn't have done what I outlined if the exercise hadn't explicitly stated $s_n = F_n$. And, there's nothing to forgive; thank you for your interest in helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the number of sequences $s_{n+1}$ ending in $n+1$ is obtained by adding $n+1$ to sequences ending in $n$ or ...

you can't add $n+1$ to a sequence ending in $n-1$ because they have the same parity. But you can substitute $n+1$ for $n-1$ at the end of a sequence because they have the same parity.

Every sequence ending in $n+1$ can be obtained in this way, because either the penultimate element is $n$ or it is less than $n-1$ (parity again).

Hence $s_{n+1}=s_n+s_{n-1}$ and it suffices to show that $s_1=s_2=1$

Comment: Nice, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A_n$ is the set of sequences corresponding to $s_n$. Pick a sequence from $A_n$, appending $n+1,n+2$ to it we get a sequence in $A_{n+2}$. Pick a sequence in $A_{n+1}$, appending $n+2$ to it gets us a sequence in $A_{n+2}$. So
we have $$\#(A_{n+2})\ge\#(A_n)+\#(A_{n+1})\implies s_{n+2}\ge s_{n}+s_{n+1}$$
where $\#$ denotes the number of elements in a set or its cardinality. Now pick a sequence in $A_{n+2}$. If the penultimate term is $n+1$, remove the last term to get a sequence in $A_{n+1}$. If the penultimate term is not $n+1$, remove the last two terms. If the reduced sequence has $n$ as its last term we get a sequence in $A_n$ and if not simply replace the last term with $n$ and we still get a member of $A_n$. So we have
$$
\#(A_{n+2})\le\#(A_n)+\#(A_{n+1})\implies s_{n+2}\le s_n+s_{n+1}\\
\therefore s_{n+2}=s_{n}+s_{n+1}
$$
Now check that $s_0=1,s_1=1$ and you're good to go.

Comment: Nice, thanks, +1.

Answer (score -1):

If you did not know beforehand that the result is Fibonacci then start by trying to find a relation for $s_n$  in terms of its previous terms.

Comment: That's trial and error, isn't it?